# Connection pool destructor prevents network communication in destructor of child objects

Tags: c++, c++11, boost-asio

I have a connection pool that uses the new thread_pool with 2 threads. I also have 2 connections on my pool. The connection pool is implemented thus:

**.hpp**

```
/// \brief Connection pool.
    struct pool : public std::enable_shared_from_this<pool> {
      pool(const pool &) = delete;
      auto operator=(const pool &) -> pool & = delete;
      explicit pool(pool_parameters config, db_parameters params) noexcept;
      ~pool();

      /// \brief Run loop.
      asio::io_context m_io_context;

      /// \brief Used to keep the io_context from running out of work.
      asio::executor_work_guard<asio::io_context::executor_type> m_work_guard;

      /// \brief Thread pool where tasks are asynchronously executed.
      asio::thread_pool m_workers;

      /// \brief Container to hold connections.
      std::vector<std::unique_ptr<dbc::connection>> m_connections;
    };
```

**.cpp**

```
pool::pool(pool_parameters config, db_parameters params) noexcept
    : m_config{std::move(config)},
      m_params{std::move(params)},
      m_work_guard{asio::make_work_guard(m_io_context)},
      m_workers{m_config.thread_pool_size} {
  m_connections.reserve(m_config.connection_pool_size);
  asio::post(m_workers, [&]() { m_io_context.run(); });
}

pool::~pool() {
  std::cerr << "~pool" << std::endl;
  m_work_guard.reset();
  m_workers.join();
  m_io_context.stop();
}
```

I also have a connection object that does a connection handshake on the constructor and a disconnect handshake on the destructor.

The problem is that by the time the connection is destroyed the pool has already stopped the work guard and so no packets are sent to the remote system.

How can I force the disconnect handshake to be done before the work guard is destroyed? I can add a manual disconnect method to each connection object but I'd like to stick to RAII.

Comment: If you want to stick to RAII, then why do you reset `m_work_guard` manually? Had you allowed constructors and destructors to do their thing, everything would be cleaned up in the right order.

Comment: Regarding to my deleted answer, you can make wrapper for `m_workers` sth like this `struct Threads { asio::thread_pool m_workers;  ~Threads() {m_workers.join(); } }`, so connections are deleted (it queues some async tasks), `m_work_guard` is deleted (`run` can end when there is no pending tasks),  threads are deleted, dtor calls `join` so we have confidence that all tasks are processed by `run`. And we remove the case where default dtor of `thread_pool` calls `stop` what breaks `io_context::run` - throws exception or fills error_code.

Comment: @rafix07 Still not sure what the problem was with your answer, implementing it solved my problem perfectly.